# Control cabinet rules

Tags: plc, enclosure, automation, industrial, regulations

I am building an electrical enclosure box equipped with a smart relay (PLC) and containing a 60W 24VDC power supply which is supplied from 230V AC. The PLC controlles a small 15W DC motor and measueres a sensor through 4-20mA signal. The question is, can this be done in a plastic industrial box where the MCUs and the small PLC is visible through the plastic:
[image: TP electric 3328-000-0000]
or is a normal metal control cabinet (with a door) mandatory? Like this:

[image: Metal control cabinet example]

Can wago connectors

[image: Wago connector] be used in it? Or DIN rail terminal blocks are needed?

What rules apply to the marking of wires? This enclosure will be sold in the EU (Hungary).

I would be realy happy if someone could answer what regulatory certifications does an enclosure like this need. Thank you!